# __func__ returns class name in debug but not in release

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm working with 12 year old legacy software written in Embarcadero C++ and I noticed:
when you use `__func__` or `__FUNC__` in debug or release configuration for 32bit, it returns `ClassName::FunctionName` but when built in debug or release configuration for 64bit, it returns only `FunctionName`.

Is that expected behaviour and can I change that?

I'd like to have `ClassName::FunctionName` in 64bit release config, too.

I'm using Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.3 Version 26.0.36039.7899

My Google skills have failed me so far, thanks in advance.

Comment: The standard `__func__` has an implementation defined value. The plain function name is as valid as any. Perhaps using a [compiler specific macro](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/FUNC) will be more consistent.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I've tried to use `__FUNC__` and provided more information in the original post. `__func__` and `__FUNC__` return `ClassName::FunctionName` only in 32bit debug or release and return `FunctionName` in 64bit debug or release.

Comment: What *problem are you trying to solve* by getting the function name?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: The problem description seems clear enough. We can speculate (e.g. have similarity between logfiles, so you can use a shared logfile parser) but the question is already sufficiently clear to be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to get the full function signature. This macro is not listed in Embarcadero documentation, so it might not work with the Classic compiler.

Output in C++ Builder 10.3.3 is like:

```
int ClassName::FunctionName(int, int)
```

If you need to remove the return value and arguments, just parse the string.